# Python3 文字列の比較で "Perl"<"Python" がなぜTrueになるのかが理解できません

Tags: python, python3

この式がTrueになるのはなぜなのでしょうか？

```
"PHP"<"Perl"<"Python"
```

文字コードで1文字ずつ比較しているようで、`"PHP"<"Perl"` がTrueになるのはわかりますが、`"Perl"<"Python"` がなぜTrueになるのかが理解できません。

4文字目の"l"と"h"では"h"の方が小さいのではないでしょうか？
`ord` 関数で調べても"l"=108,"h"=104となっています。

どなたかご教授ください。

Comment: こちらの記事 [シーケンスの比較](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/72100/26370) と同件ですね。

Comment: 4文字目ではなく、2文字目で比較が行われています。`"Pe" < "Py" => True`, `"e" < "y" => True`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

文字列の比較では、「辞書順の比較」が行われます。つまり辞書に単語が載っている順番のように、先頭の文字から順番に比較が行われます。

`"Perl"` と `"Python"` を比較するときは、

1. まず最初の 1 文字を比較して `P` と `P` で等しい
2. 等しいので 2 文字目を比較して `e` と `y` で `y` の方が大きい

という順番で比較が行われ、`"Perl" < "Python"` は `True`、ということになります。

公式ドキュメント: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons

Comment: 早速の回答ありがとうございます。わかりやすい説明で理解できました。ありがとうございました。