# Pythonで文字列に対して比較演算子を使ったときの仕組みがわかりません

Tags: python, python3

現在Pythonを独学中の初学者です。
Pythonで使われる比較演算子についてお聞かせください。

```
'Perl' < 'Python'
```

上記2つの文字列を比較した際に、Trueが返ってくる仕組みがわかりません。
1文字目の'P'同士を比較した場合、Falseが返ってくるはずであると認識しておりますが、
なぜFalseではなくTrueが返ってくるのでしょうか。

Comment: こちらの記事 [シーケンスの比較](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/72100/26370) と類似の内容でしょう。その回答はこの質問にも当てはまります。

Comment: kunifさん　リンクまで貼っていただきありがとうございます。解決することができました。